# wacom and myscript set handwritng recognition function

Tags: scribe, handwriting, handwriting-recognition, wacom

im not sure if its the right place to put my question, but i think maybe get an answer here.

the last few days thinking about a way to make μυ work easier.
What I want is to write by hand and convert into text on the computer.
namely when I am on a page with multiple text forms like this im writing now,
when i choose a text form with a pen (like wacom graphic tablet) write on a surface and the automaticaly when i stop or pressing a button the text turn into text in the form.

my title say about wacom because i found bamboo scribe.. if someone uses this please explain me whats can do and if can work for me.

i test myscript. with fullscreen tool wich you can write everywhere on the screen is easiest but when you finish you have to press a button on the program to insert the text in the selected area.

so my question is there any way to press that button with the button placed on stylus pen?

i saw that you can set functions when a button clicked on the wacom tablet or on pen.

i have not bought yet anything because im searching if is out there anything could do what i want better. something made for that particular job

Thanks and sorry for my bad english..